# "NPM install" command line cannot run in LARAVEL project directory

Tags: laravel, npm

I want to work with webpack and Laravel
I'm trying to install Mix in my Laravel project.

So i have installed node and npm succesfully.
When i run node -v and npm -v in vscode it show me the version number so i think the install is ok.

But when i go in the Laravel project directory and try to run "npm -v" or "npm install" i have a message like "npm: The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, file
script or executable program"...

Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My bad...

I had another session of Vscode runnign on the other screen and i didnt see it.
I closed all vscode session and reboot and it work

Thank you very much!